# Javascript loop selects all rectangles

Tags: javascript, canvas

Whenever I click on a single rectangle on the canvas, it clears all rectangles. How can I clear only the rectangle I clicked on the canvas? I guess the problem is with the for cycle in my code since it loops through all the rectangles.

```
for(var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++){
    // Check if the x and y coordinates are inside the rectangle
    if(x > rect[i].x && x < rect[i].x + rect[i].width
        && y > rect[i].y && y < rect[i].y + rect[i].height)
    {
        // If true, clear the rectangle
        for(var j = 0; j < rect.length; j++){
            ctx.clearRect(rect[j].x,rect[j].y,rect[j].width,rect[j].height);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly the problem is your second for loop. After you find the right rectangle you loop through them all again. Try this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < rect.length; i++){
    // Check if the x and y coordinates are inside the rectangle
    if(x > rect[i].x && x < rect[i].x + rect[i].width
        && y > rect[i].y && y < rect[i].y + rect[i].height)
    {
        // If true, clear the rectangle
        ctx.clearRect(rect[i].x,rect[i].y,rect[i].width,rect[i].height);
        break; //break out of the for loop since the rect was found
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer works. However, can you further explain it? Thanks.
What if I wanted to loop it two or more times and then break it? Adding a variable inside the loop and then an if, so if it reaches to a certain number break?

Comment: You were on the right track. The problem that you had is AFTER you found the correct rectangle, you were looping over all the rectangles again and clearing them all. Since you have already found the right rectangle once your enter the if statement, all you need to do is clear it. Make since?